# How to sort columns in Vue when the values to sort are the result of calculations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've found many resources for sorting data that is already in an array but can't find anything on sorting dynamically generated data.

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Program</th>
        <th>Rewards</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="program in programs" :key="program.id">
        <td>{{ program.program_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ pointValue(program) | percent }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

pointValue() is a method which calculates and returns a value which is displayed as a %. this is the Rewards column. i would like the table to be sortable by Programs and by Rewards. (Program is just a string).

Comment: You need to provide more details on the sorting requirements, the ``pointValue`` function, and show some attempt to solve the problem. It would be better to show the script part as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create computed array for programs using `map` and `sort` method and iterate it instead

```
computed: {
  computedPrograms() {
    return this.programs
      .map(program => {
        return {
           ...program,
           value: this.pointValue(program)
        }
      })
      .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
  }
}
```

```
<tr v-for="program in computedPrograms" :key="program.id">
  <td>{{ program.program_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ program.value | percent }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! "this.pointValue(program)" I didn't know you could do that, so that certainly makes everything much more clear.

Comment: @wilfra please mark the answer as correct. Reward  the help!